# How to append rows in pandas.DataFrame in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to append rows in a new created pandas dataframe

```
###expression
for i in active_brain_regions:
    indices = np.where(LM == i)
    expr = gene[indices]
    mean = np.mean(expr)
    dat= [[i, mean, str("nifti")]]
    dd = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns = ['region', 'mean expr', 'gene_id'])
    dd.append(dd)
```

dd should look like

```
 0.0  -0.424069   nifti
 1.0       -1.0   nifti
 .
 . 
 .
 11.0    0.23352   nifti
```

But after running the for loop dd is just a dataframe of size (1,3) with the last entry of region 11..

Answer (score 4):

You can assign back, because is used pandas method [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
dd = dd.append(dd)
```

Or create list of DataFrames by pure python `append` (working inplace) and use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) only once:

```
L = []
for i in active_brain_regions:
    indices = np.where(LM == i)
    expr = gene[indices]
    mean = np.mean(expr)
    dat= [[i, mean, str("nifti")]]
    dd = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns = ['region', 'mean expr', 'gene_id'])
    L.append(dd)

 df = pd.concat(L, ignore_index=True)
```

But fastest solution should be create list of lists and pass to `DataFrame` constructor only once:

```
L = []
for i in active_brain_regions:
    indices = np.where(LM == i)
    expr = gene[indices]
    mean = np.mean(expr)
    dat= [[i, mean, str("nifti")]]
    L.append(dat)

 df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns = ['region', 'mean expr', 'gene_id'])
```